# Recommendation how to migrate Spring batch app to AWS

Tags: spring-batch, aws-batch

I have a spring batch app that is running once a day on a windows server (Windows scheduler). The app running 6 jobs that ingest data from txt files , csv files and also data from external databases in to my local one. I am quite satisfied with spring batch. It’s definitely doing the job and removing a lot of code.

We are now transferring our solution to AWS. I know that AWS has its own batch solution and per my understanding if I will want to use AWS batch then I will need to start the development from scratch. I am not sure what are the options that are valid for me.

I would like to hear if someone ever experience with migrating spring batch app to AWS. Is it preferable to start the development in AWS or there is an option to migrate spring batch app ?

Also, does AWS batch have API’s to handle files (like spring) or I will need to deal with the parsing and loading ?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> per my understanding if I will want to use AWS batch then I will need to start the development from scratch.

Not necessarily. A job definition in AWS is basically a docker image with some configuration parameters: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/userguide/create-job-definition.html. So if you create a docker image for your Spring Batch job, you should be able to run it as a Job in AWS without having to rewrite it.

Comment: Thanks Mahmoud, would it be a bit “wrong path” ? I mean using a batch framework inside of AWS batch ?

Comment: No, Spring Batch and AWS Batch are not at the same level. Spring Batch provides a framework to develop batch jobs. AWS Batch provides a framework to deploy, run, schedule and scale containers on AWS infrastructure. AWS batch is at a higher level, it does not provides APIs like Spring Batch. What AWS Batch calls a job is actually a container (see step 10 in the link above).